# How can I use regexp captures in Delphi 10.3 replace feature?

Tags: delphi

I would like to replace in my source files all of the

`constructor X.init(...`

to

`constructor X.Create(...`

where X is the current class type (a regexp capture)

I tried this in the Replace dialog of the IDE:

Text to find: `constructor(.*)\.init`

Replace with: `constructor$1\.Create`

But the result is:

`constructor$1.Create(...`

Instead of the expected current type.

Comment: Can't you just use the refactoring feature?

Comment: What about the occurrences of Create in the classes' declarations?

Comment: @Olivier Till this time I use Delphi 7 and I forgot about the refactoring feature. It is too late now because in the declaration sections I replaced the init-s by Create-s all in the 2k occurances :(

Comment: @MartynA Till this time I use Delphi 7 and I forgot about the refactoring feature. It is too late now because in the declaration sections I replaced the init-s by Create-s all in the 2k occurances :(

Comment: Just revert the change in your revision control system and go again

Comment: As for how to use captures in the replacement text iirc syntax is \1 \2 etc. You might find that a good text editor like Notepad++ has better regex find replace tools.